# Shell Script returning siblings name in place of children

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am creating a shell script to create thumbnails of videos inside a folder.

Fist step is to get name of videos in that folder.

i have a directory name 9feb. In that directory i have folder as

```
folder 1
folder 2
folder 3
sample
tst.sh
```

tst.sh is the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC= /home/user4/media/videos/9feb/sample

for FILE in `ls $SRC`
do

echo $FILE 

done
```

I want to get name of files in sample folder, but script is returning folder and file name in which script is located.

Output:

```
folder 1 
folder 2 
folder 3 
sample 
tst.sh
```

Desired output

```
a.mp4
b.mp4
```

a.mp4 and b.mp4 are in sample folder

Comment: Please specify desired output, and actual (unwanted) output.

Comment: actual (unwanted ) output is above

and desired output is 

a.mp4
b.mp4

a.mp4 and b.mp4 are in sample folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SRC=/home/user4/media/videos/9feb/sample
for FILE in "$SRC"/*
do
  echo $FILE
done
```

Your problem probably is the space between `=` and the path.

Parsing the output of `ls` is not recommended, and using a command substitution like you do will break if file names have special characters or even spaces.  Globbing (`*`) is safe from that standpoint, and avoids creating a subshell.

Please note that if you need to extract the name of the file (without the path), you can do it this way :

```
FILE="${FILE%/}"   # Remove trailing slash, if any
NAME="${FILE##*/}" # Remove all up to and including last slash
```

You can also use :

```
NAME="$(basename "$FILE")"
```

Some will find it more readable, but it costs a subshell.

Comment: thank you. I also try this before it was not working but now it is working